# Problem while using cd command in cygwin based windows batch script

Tags: batch-file, cygwin, command, cd

I am facing a problem in windows batch script. I have installed cygwin in  my system. So i am using bash commands inside my batch script for efficiency. Consider the below command

```
cp -rf D:/Ashok E:/Data
E:
cd E:/Data
cd E:/Data
```

Output is

```
c:>sample.bat
c:>cp -rf D:/Ashok E:/Data
c:>E:
E:>cd E:/Data
E:/Data>cd E:/Data
The system cannot find the specified path
```

While in the same folder (E:/data), i am trying to do the cd, that time i am getting error message. Because it treated that entire "E:/Data" as a folder name. How to get rid of this problem. What we can do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the proper back slash in the cd command will solve the problem. But cp command is supporting both the slashes.

```
c:>sample.bat
c:>cp -rf D:/Ashok E:/Data
c:>E:
E:>cd E:\Data
E:/Data>cd E:\Data
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `cygdrive` prefix?

```
cd /cygdrive/e/Data
```

Comment: Its not working. This will work only in cygwin terminal, not in the dos terminal. I have written a batch script, its running on dos terminal.